# How do I iterate through a nested dict/hash-map in Clojure to custom-flatten/transform my data structure?

Tags: clojure

I have something that looks like this:

```
{:person-123 {:xxx [1 5]
              :zzz [2 3 4]}
 :person-456 {:yyy [6 7]}}
```

And I want to transform it so it looks like this:

```
[{:person "123" :item "xxx"}
 {:person "123" :item "zzz"}
 {:person "456" :item "yyy"}]
```

This is a `flatten`-like problem, and I know I can convert the keywords into strings by calling `name` on them, but I couldn't come across a convenient way to do this.

This is how I did it, but it seems inelegant (nested `for` loops, I'm looking at you):

```
(require '[clojure.string :refer [split]])
(into [] 
      (apply concat
             (for [[person nested-data] input-data]
                  (for [[item _] nested-data]
                       {:person (last (split (name person) #"person-"))
                        :item (name item)}))))
```

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: @Shlomi I've updated my answer to include my (inelegant) solution.

Comment: See if you can push back on the input format: `:person-123` is a much worse map key than, for example, `[:person 123]`, or indeed even just `123` if the `:person` part can be implied/assumed. If you are producing this map yourself, try to produce it so it's reasonable to begin with and doesn't need this weird string-processing step intermingled with the (reasonable) flattening step.

Comment: @amalloy I agree that the input format is sub-par. That is unfortunately a constraint that I am working with, and instead of massively modifying my code to work with that format, I have decided instead to use this intermediate step to transform the input data into a form the rest of my code can more easily consume.

Comment: Why convert to a vector?

Comment: @Thumbnail It doesn't necessarily have to be a vector. A list would work too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution is not too bad, as for the nested for loops, well `for` actually supports nested loops, so you could write it as:

```
(vec 
  (for [[person nested-data] input-data
       [item _] nested-data]
    {:person (last (clojure.string/split (name person) #"person-"))
     :item   (name item)}))
```

personally, I tend to use `for` exclusively for that purpose (nested loops), otherwise I am usually more comfortable with `map` et al. But thats just a personal preference.

I also very much agree with @amalloy's comment on the question, I would put some effort into having a better looking map structure to begin with.

Comment: Nice! I can think of two small improvements: One, simply use `vec` around the `for` loop to flatten it into a vector. And two, you could use `:let` to do the name transormation only once per person, `(for [[person nested-data] input-data :let [person-name ,,,]] ,,,)`.

Comment: amalloy & glts, good points, updated answer. As for using `:let`, I dont particularly like to use it unless it is clearly helpful, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Minor point: I'd use a threading macro for the `:person` value: `(-> person name (split #"person-") last)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(let [x {:person-123 {:xxx [1 5]
                              :zzz [2 3 4]}
                 :person-456 {:yyy [6 7]}}]

            (clojure.pprint/pprint
                (mapcat
                    (fn [[k v]]
                        (map (fn [[k1 v1]]
                                 {:person (clojure.string/replace (name k) #"person-" "") :item (name k1)}) v))
                    x))
            )
```

I am not sure if there is a single high-order function, at least in the core, that does what you want in one go.

On the other hand, similar methods exist in GNU R reshape library, which, by the way, has been recreated for clojure:
https://crossclj.info/ns/grafter/0.8.6/grafter.tabular.melt.html#_melt-column-groups which might interest you.

This is how it works in Gnu R: http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good solutions so far. All I would add is a simplification with `keys`:

```
(vec
     (for [[person nested-data] input-data
           item (map name (keys nested-data))]
       {:person (clojure.string/replace-first
                  (name person)
                  #"person-" "")
        :item   item}))
```

Note btw the near universal preference for replace over last/split. Guessing the spirit of the transformation is "lose the leading person- prefix", `replace` says that better. If OTOH the spirit is "find the number and use that", a bit of regex to isolate the digits would be truer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(reduce-kv (fn [ret k v]
             (into ret (map (fn [v-k]
                              {:person (last (str/split (name k) #"-"))
                               :item   (name v-k)}) 
                            (keys v))))
           []
           {:person-123 {:xxx [1 5] :zzz [2 3 4]}
            :person-456 {:yyy [6 7]}})

=> [{:person "123", :item "xxx"} 
    {:person "123", :item "zzz"} 
    {:person "456", :item "yyy"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are three solutions.

The first solution uses Python-style lazy generator functions via `lazy-gen` and `yield` functions [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  I think this method is the simplest since the inner loop produces maps and the outer loop produces a sequence. Also, the inner loop can run zero, one, or multiple times for each outer loop. With `yield` you don't need to think about that part.

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [clojure.walk :as walk]
    [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.string :as ts]
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def data
  {:person-123 {:xxx [1 5]
                :zzz [2 3 4]}
   :person-456 {:yyy [6 7]}})

(defn reformat-gen [data]
  (t/lazy-gen
    (doseq [[outer-key outer-val] data]
      (let [int-str (str/replace (name outer-key) "person-" "")]
        (doseq [[inner-key inner-val] outer-val]
          (let [inner-key-str (name inner-key)]
            (t/yield {:person int-str :item inner-key-str})))))))
```

---

If you really want to be "pure", the following is another solution. However, with this solution I made a couple of errors and required many, many debug printouts to fix. This version uses `tupelo.core/glue` instead of `concat` since it is "safer" and verifies that the collections are all maps, all vectors/list, etc.

```
(defn reformat-glue [data]
  (apply t/glue
    (forv [[outer-key outer-val] data]
      (let [int-str (str/replace (name outer-key) "person-" "")]
        (forv [[inner-key inner-val] outer-val]
          (let [inner-key-str (name inner-key)]
            {:person int-str :item inner-key-str}))))))
```

Both methods give the same answer:

```
(newline) (println "reformat-gen:")
(pprint (reformat-gen data))
(newline) (println "reformat-glue:")
(pprint (reformat-glue data))

reformat-gen:
({:person "123", :item "xxx"}
 {:person "123", :item "zzz"}
 {:person "456", :item "yyy"})

reformat-glue:
[{:person "123", :item "xxx"}
 {:person "123", :item "zzz"}
 {:person "456", :item "yyy"}]
```

---

If you wanted to be "super-pure", here is a third solution (although I think this one is trying too hard!). Here we use the ability of the `for` macro to have nested elements in a single expression. `for` can also embed `let` expressions inside itself, although here that leads to duplicate evaluation of `int-str`.

```
(defn reformat-overboard [data]
  (for [[outer-key outer-val] data
        [inner-key inner-val] outer-val
        :let [int-str       (str/replace (name outer-key) "person-" "") ; duplicate evaluation
              inner-key-str (name inner-key)]]
    {:person int-str :item inner-key-str}))
(newline)
(println "reformat-overboard:")
(pprint (reformat-overboard data))

reformat-overboard:
({:person "123", :item "xxx"}
 {:person "123", :item "zzz"}
 {:person "456", :item "yyy"})
```

I would probably stick with the first one since it is (at least to me) much simpler and more bulletproof. YMMV.

---

## Update:

Notice that the 3rd method yields a single sequence of maps, even though there are 2 nested `for` iterations happening.  This is different than having two nested `for` expressions, which would yield a sequence of a sequence of maps.